# Scala Generic JSON parser with default value support

Tags: scala, generics

I have a custom Jackson deserializer written in scala. Structure is as follows.

```
override def deserialize(jp: JsonParser, ctx: DeserializationContext): Item = {

    val node: JsonNode = jp.getCodec.readTree(jp)

    // few double fields
    val usageHours = node.get("usageHours").asDouble()
    val usageUnits = node.get("usageUnits").asDouble()

    // few string fields
    val accountId = node.get("accountId").asText()
    val accountName = node.get("accountName").asText()

    // few long fields
    val cardinality = node.get("cardinality").asLong()

    // few date fields
    val endDateTime = customDeserializer.convert(node.get("startDateTime").asText())

    // few optionals with default values
    val engine = Option(node.get("engine")).map(value => value.asText()).getOrElse(Constants.Unknown)

    // case class object
    Item(usageHours, 
         usageUnits, 
         accountId, 
         accountName, 
         cardinality, 
         endDateTime, 
         engine)


}
```

Problem is that there are too many fields to parse and obviously calling node.get() or Option(node.get) for each field is not good. I'm trying to write a **generic** method getValueForJsonKey() which can

1. Parse key values and return them as either text, long, double, or date as required by the user.
2. This method should also accept a default value which is optional. If any user provided key is missing in the JSON, default value will be returned.

Here's what i came up with

```
 // Basically trying to identify the return type from the default value passed by the user
 // This will not work if the user doesn’t pass a default value.

 private def parseValueForJsonKey [A] (node: JsonNode, key: String, defaultValue: A): A = {

  val parsedValue = Option(node.get(key)).map(value => {
    defaultValue match {
      case _: String => value.asText()
      case _: Double => value.asDouble()
      case _: Long => value.asLong()        
      case _: ZonedDateTime => customDateDeserializer.convert(value)
      case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"Unsupported type. Cannot parse ${key} to other than supported types")
    }
  })

  parsedValue match{
     case Some(value) => value.asInstanceOf[A] 
     case None => defaultValue
  }
 }
```

This clearly doesn't work and is not the right way to do it. I'm sure there are better ways to do this. Appreciate your help.

**Revision 2**

```
def parseValueForJsonKeyWithReturnType[A: TypeTag](
     node: JsonNode, 
     key: String, 
     defaultValue: Any = None
): A = {

    val parsedValue = Option(node.get(key)).map(value => {
      typeOf[A] match {
        case t if t =:= typeOf[String] =>
          value.asText()
        case t if t =:= typeOf[Double] =>
          value.asDouble()
        case t if t =:= typeOf[Long] =>
          value.asLong()
        case t if t =:= typeOf[ZonedDateTime] =>
          zonedDateTimeDeserializer.convert(value.asText())
        case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"Parsing to ${typeOf[A]} isn't supported by custom deserializer")
      }
    })

    parsedValue.getOrElse(defaultValue).asInstanceOf[A]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually quite close. You need to:

1. Fix scoping (you seem to try to use local variable `parsedValue` outside of the method),
2. remove `.get` calls (neither `value` nor `defaultValue` are `Option`s)
3. remove `.getClass` (`asInstanceOf` needs a type parameter and `A` is already a type) from the `Some(value)` case and remove the cast completely from the `None` case.

But a better way to write it would be

```
val parsedValue = /* what you have */    
parsedValue.getOrElse(defaultValue).asInstanceOf[A]
```

Note that because of type erasure, `asInstanceOf[A]` itself won't throw an exception if the type isn't correct, but your code already handles that part.

Comment: I've added a **revision 2** which works as expected. Made use of _typetag_ in the reflect api. Only thing remaining is that i want to add a validation to make sure `defaultValue` has the same type as `A`during compile time. Can you provide some inputs on that, please?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping me out. 

1. That was due to bad code formatting. It is actually inside the method. Updated the question.

2 & 3. Yes, you're right. Fixed it. I prefer the way you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala). It has [build in support of default values](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/blob/ff0fab7849f41a6fac062fa138eb34c822e4fc7a/macros/src/test/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter_scala/macros/JsonCodecMakerSpec.scala#L789-L808) for case class fields, so in such cases it does not require to write custom codecs.

On the other hand it allows [writing of custom codecs](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/blob/dfe1d814de69d21b62e0d0c6dde32c1f909ec083/core/src/test/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter_scala/core/UserAPI.scala#L17-L139) without need of redundant intermediate AST or/and string representations.

Also it is the most [secure](https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json/pull/205#issuecomment-392472719) and [efficient](http://jmh.morethan.io/?source=https://plokhotnyuk.github.io/jsoniter-scala/oraclejdk8.json) parser comparing to other JSON libraries.